# Operations with CartesianIndex

Tags: julia

I'd like to know how can I operate with CartesianIndex. For example I have array

```
julia> A = rand(1:5, 10, 2)
10×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2 5
 1 1
 4 5
 4 1
 2 1
 4 1
 2 4
 1 5
 2 5
 4 4
```

and I want to save all numbers which stay near (in pair) with number 1. I can use `c=findall(x->x==1, A)`, but I will have a cartensian indexes of "1".
There is function `x=getindex.(c, [1 2])` it makes an array which I can change, but I don't know how to convert it back to CartesianIndex. And I think that must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand your problem - what exactly do you mean by "stay near (in pair) with number 1"? Your `c` just gets all the actual 1s in your matrix, not numbers "near" to 1. Why do you want to change the CartesianIndex into an Array? And why do you want to change it back?

Comment: Can you tell us what you want to do after `c = findall(x -> x==1, A)`?

Comment: I'd like to save all values which are at the same row with 1s, but in another column in my matrix. For example A[2,1]=1, I need to save A[2,2] into an array. Sorry its my first question here. @Nils Gudat

Comment: To be more precise, can you add a code snippet to your question that shows the expected output that you are trying to generate?

Comment: What output do you want for the second row, where both the left and the right columns have a 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A[view(A.==1,:,[2,1])]
```

This literally returns "all numbers which stay in pair with number 1".

The order of returned numbers is columnar. If you want to return it by rows:

```
 A'[view(A.==1,:,[2,1])']
```

Example:

```
julia> A = rand(1:5, 10, 2)
10×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4
 3  3
 1  3
 3  3
 5  1
 1  5
 2  1
 3  3
 1  3
 2  3

julia> A'[view(A.==1,:,[2,1])']
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 3
 5
 5
 2
 3
```

If you rather want full rows than use `filter!`:

```
julia> filter!((x)->(1 in x), collect(eachrow(A)))
6-element Array{SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,2},Tuple{Int64,Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}},true},1}:
 [1, 4]
 [1, 3]
 [5, 1]
 [1, 5]
 [2, 1]
 [1, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you, It's almost what I looked for. If I have 3×10 array and I want to have an array which consist only with rows (of first array) where the value of first column is 1? Like 
1;2;3 - first row,
1:5:4- second row of new array

Comment: filter! makes a subarray. Is it possible to convert it into a new simple array 2×6.I tryed but I can't.

Comment: Use vectorized `collect` as in `collect.(filter!((x)->(1 in x), collect(eachrow(A))))`